# React leaflet side-by-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, leaflet

I wanted to show two tile layers side by side, like the plugin side-by-side for leaflet (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side).

However, I am not sure how to do this with react. Is there a way to use the above mentioned plugin in react? Do you have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this functionality?

[image: side-by-side plugin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a component and use the native leaflet code inside a `useEffect` after importing the plugin.

```
import "leaflet-side-by-side";
...

const Map = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const osmLayer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var stamenLayer = L.tileLayer(
      "https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      {
        attribution:
          'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, ' +
          '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; ' +
          "Map data {attribution.OpenStreetMap}",
        minZoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 16
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    L.control.sideBySide(stamenLayer, osmLayer).addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" />;
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-side-by-side-vt1js)

Comment: That works of course, but it doesn't really interact with react-leaflet, the thing we usually use for the rest of the map.

Comment: The question is not about react-leaflet. I don't get you.

Comment: kboul, did you find a way to have side-by-side with react-leaflet-v3?

Comment: Have not tried it yet but should be feasible.