# Restricted access to Leaflet TileLayers in React inside a side-by-side component

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

On a React app that displays maps, I made a side-by-side comparator using the [leaflet-side-by-side](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side) plugin (I followed the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374092/react-leaflet-side-by-side)) that works fine on its own.

However, some of the maps aren't free and I want to restrict access to them (and prevent requests for these tiles). For now, I've made it so that the tiles won't display unless you enter the right password.
So basically, I need to update the locked TileLayer after it has been rendered. When I use react-leaflet, I just use setUrl to update the TileLayer when the password matches :

```
const LockedLayer = ({ lockedUrl, attribution }) => {
  const pwd = Config.PWD;
  const [inputPwd, setInputPwd] = useState(null);

  const tileLayerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pwd === inputPwd) {
      tileLayerRef.current.setUrl(lockedUrl);
    }
  });

  return <TileLayer attribution={attribution} url="" ref={tileLayerRef} />;
};
```

which works perfectly fine.

But for leaflet-side-by-side, I need to use native Leaflet, which doesn't behave the same. The same code applied to a TileLayer created by L.tileLayer has no effect, even though the URL is correctly updated, the map will not update its content despite the layer changing (because it is inside of a hook, I assume). Like I mentioned, I copy-pasted the code from a thread before adding my own layers, which looks like:

```
import "leaflet-side-by-side";
...

const Map = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const osmLayer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { attribution: 'OSM' }).addTo(map);

    const lockedLayer = LeafletLockedLayer(
      "PROTECTED_URL", { attribution: 'credits'}
    ).addTo(map);

    L.control.sideBySide(lockedLayer, osmLayer).addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" />;
};
```

```
const LeafletLockedLayer = ({ lockedUrl, attribution }) => {
  const pwd = Config.PWD;
  const [inputPwd, setInputPwd] = useState(null);

  const tileLayer = L.tileLayer("", { attribution: attribution });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pwd === inputPwd) {
      tileLayer.setUrl(lockedUrl);
    }
  });

  return tileLayer;
};
```

So far I've unsuccessfully tried:

- using map.invalidateSize() to force an update
- using a component similar to LockedLayer, but with L.tileLayer instead of
- rendering the map with a setTimeout (kind of glad this isn't the solution)
- only adding the TileLayer to the map if it is unlocked (it never shows up)

What I'm looking for is either a way to update and redraw the layers in leaflet-side-by-side, another way to restrict access to some layers, or an alternative to the plugin that would allow me to use react-leaflet.

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: You say "even though the URL is correctly updated, the map will not update its content despite the layer changing"...I"m not understanding what that means.  Where in this second code block do you change the tileUrl?  Are you able to reproduce your issue in a codesandbox?  Why can you not just bring your reference to `map` and your 2 tile layers outside the scope of that useEffect, and then in another effect, call `setUrl` on them?

Comment: That is what I do. What I tried first was to replace the TileLayer by a L.tileLayer that would be added to the map. The LockedLayer works just the same, the layer's URL is updated, but it does not fire any request to that URL. I tried it in another effect too, but still no request.

If I bring map outside of useEffect, I get an error indicating that the MapContainer is not initialized, which I have no idea how to get around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different configurations, I think the only way to get the layer to fire its requests again post-update is to create it alongside the map in `useEffect`. The `LeafletLockedLayer` I wrote cannot be used inside `useEffect` (since it uses hooks), but a simple way to get around that is to replace its own `useEffect` by a makeshift one with `setTimeout`/`setInterval`. Although I'd rather not use those, I don't have time to look for a better solution, and the time it takes to read the password is shorter than loading the tiles anyway.

Here's a working `LeafletLockedLayer` than can be created inside the same `useEffect` as the map like it is meant to:

```
const LeafletLockedLayer = ({ lockedUrl, attribution }) => {
  const storedPwd = Config.layersPwd;
  let pwd = null;

  const tileLayer = L.tileLayer("", { attribution: attribution });

  const interval = setInterval(() => updateLayer(), 100);
  const updateLayer = () => {
    if (pwd === storedPwd) {
      tileLayer.setUrl(lockedUrl);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  };

  return tileLayer;
};
```